# Alterar estados entre componentes pai e filho com modal

Tags: react

Possuo um componente que preciso controlar quando o modal vai abrir/fechar, onde o componente pai é o componente que vai abrir o modal e o componente filho (que é o modal) vai fechar.

No meu componente pai, criei uma variável pra controlar quando vai abrir/fechar o modal:

```
const [openFullScreenModal, setOpenFullScreenModal] = useState(false)
```

No meu template do componente pai possuo um botão que altera o valor dessa variável para abrir o modal:

```
<button onClick={() => setOpenFullScreenModal(true)}>Abre modal</button>
```

e por fim, possui o componente modal:

```
<ModalFullScreen
   title="Permissões do grupo"
   onCloseModal={setOpenFullScreenModal()}
   open={openFullScreenModal}
/>
```

No meu componente filho estou passando a propriedade `open` com o valor da variável do componente pai e a propriedade `onCloseModal` que ao fechar o componente filho (modal) deve alterar a variável openFullScreenModal do componente pai para `false`.

No meu componente filho, recebo o valor de open através da `props` e também possuo uma função para passar para o componente pai o valor `false` ao clicar no botão fechar do meu modal:

```
 const ModalFullScreen = (props) => {

    const { title, FormComponent, open } = props
    const handleClose = () => {
       this.props.onCloseModal(false)
    }
```

No template do meu modal, eu utilizo a propriedade open para definir quando for aberta e ao fechar, uso a função handleClose para passar para o componente pai o valor false para fechar o modal:

```
<Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
```

Quando acesso o componente pai que possui o botão para abrir o modal, eu recebo diversos erros vindos do componente ModalFullScreen:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an
>   infinite loop.

Como posso fazer pra corrigir este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta substituir esse trecho

```
<ModalFullScreen
   title="Permissões do grupo"
   onCloseModal={setOpenFullScreenModal()}
   open={openFullScreenModal}
/>
```

por

```
<ModalFullScreen
   title="Permissões do grupo"
   onCloseModal={setOpenFullScreenModal}
   open={openFullScreenModal}
/>
```

Perceba que na segunda forma estamos fornecendo a referência da função para que quando o seu componente filho executar a chamada `this.props.onCloseModal(false)` você esteja na verdade executando a referência da função pai (que na verdade é setOpenFullScreenModal).

O que provavelmente está ocorrendo é que o seu componente pai executa indefinidas vezes a função `setOpenFullScreenModal()` quando declarada dessa forma em seu componente filho.

[Na documentação oficial do React existe um trecho que explica como realizar um bind de uma função para um componente](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Espero ter lhe ajudado

Comment: Tinha feito algo parecido e funcionou, tentei com seu código e também funcionou, só tive que alterar o this.props.onCloseModal(false) para const { onCloseModal } = props e na função handleClose chamei o onCloseModal(false). Obrigado.